# How to distribute google play store application to limited peoples

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk

how to make invisible my android app to everyone from google play store.
only specific peoples can download it through link given or any other procedure. 
mean is everyone can't find app on play store by just search app name.

Or tell me any other solution close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Withing Google play you can use **Alpha** and **Beta** testers to restrict the distribution of your app.

You can define a list of users. They will be the only able to get the app. Once done you update your app in google play, wait few hours and then google play will generate a link. You just have to send this link to your users and they can install the app.

This is the summary of the Google documentation ( in better english than mine )

- You don't need a production APK to publish an alpha/beta app.
- Users need a Google Account (@gmail.com) or a Google Apps account to join a test.
- If you're testing an existing app that you've published before, only users in your test group will receive an update for your alpha/beta version. If you're testing a new app that you haven't published before, only users in your test group  can find and download your app.
- After publishing an alpha/beta APK for the first time, it may take a few hours for your test link to be available to testers. If you publish additional changes, they may take several hours to be available for testers.

You have the full documentation [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

Comment: peoples can't search it through name?
just can view through link?

Comment: Alpha or Beta restrictions?
can you please explain briefly?

Comment: The app will be visible only for the predefined testers. The public cannot search for it. I have updated my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont explicitly need it on the play store, [TestFairy](http://testfairy.com) is a very powerful tool. I use it to distribute to selected people until I'm ready to share it with the world.
The API is very simple and informative.
You can also build and upload versions directly from Android Studio.